# How to calcuate the cost when moving data from azure datalake to google BigQuery

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have a Datafactory pipeline in Azure to move a on-premise SQL table to Azure blob storage Gen2 in parquet format. I think the majority cost would come from the Azure storage, right?

Now we want to move those data to BigQuery. Due to our security policy, we still need the Datafactory pipeline to read from SQL table. So we create a databrick notebook to read the parquet file and move to BigQuery using the Spark BigQuery connector. Now I need to estimate the total cost. On top of the Azure storage, do we have to pay some kind of egress cost to move data out of Azure storage? And does google would charge us some kind of ingress cost to move data to BQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- All inbound or ingress data transfers to Azure data centers from on-premises environments are free. However, outbound data transfers incur [charges](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/bandwidth/).
- Data migration from other platforms into BigQuery is [free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/pricing#migrations_from_other_platforms).
- To estimate the cost of Google Cloud Platform services, you can use the [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @Ismail's answer:

The migration from other platforms is [free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/pricing#migrations_from_other_platforms) when the [BigQuery Data Transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/introduction) service is used; however, this is not the case if the data is moved to BigQuery using the Spark BigQuery connector.

The connector writes data to BigQuery by writing it first to Cloud Storage (GCS) and then loading it into BigQuery, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#writing-data-to-bigquery):

> Notice that the process writes the data first to GCS and then loads it to BigQuery, a GCS bucket must be configured to indicate the temporary data location.

Cloud Storage princing depends on the [Storage class](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) used and the location of the bucket; so, asuming a Standard class, your migration process will generate charges for:

- [Data storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing); and
- [Operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing)

Loading the data from Cloud Storage to BigQuery is [free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free); however, there might be network egress fees if the bucket location is not on the same region/multi-region than the dataset.

Finally, once your data is in BigQuery it will be subject to the [BigQuery Storage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage).

I suggest to check both the [Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#top_of_page) and [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#top_of_page) complete pricing documentation to check for details, limitations and some examples on how the pricing work.